# .NET MVC URL IgnoreRoute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my application, I am having problems getting a stylesheet because it is using the URL, and trying to find a corresponding controller. For Example,

I have the following in one of my views:

```
<link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Which when the page loads, throws a 500 error, and tells me that...

```
www.mysite.com/design/Content/css/styles.css could not be found
```

It is using **design** as the area, because that is the name of the package it is in.

What do I need to do in order to hit my static css file at the above address, without it trying to find a controller named "Content"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the html be rendered using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/css/styles.css") %>" />
```

Or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/styles.css")" />
```

(If you are using Razor).

I dont think this is an issue with your MVC routes, but more that you are not resolving the url correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a domain-relative path rather than an application-relative path.

Remove the `~`.